# Why does this arduino code using port manipulation not work?

Tags: arduino

I tried using port manipulation for a Arduino Mega 2560 using the pin locations from this website

https://harperjiangnew.blogspot.com/2013/05/arduino-port-manipulation-on-mega-2560.html?show Comment=1563802820673

but it keeps giving an error.

The programme is for an Arduino mega 2560

The code is for an Arduino Mega 2560

```
void setup(){
 PORTA =  B0000000; 
 PORTC =  B0000000; 
}

void loop(){
 PORTA =  B1000110;
 PortC =  B0111000;
 delay(1000);
 PortA =  B0100000;
 delay(500);
 PORTA =  B1110000;
 PortC =  B0001110;
 delay(1000);
 PortA =  B0001000;
 delay(500);
 PORTA =  B0011100;
 PortC =  B1100010;
 delay(1000);
 PortA =  B0000100;
 delay(500);
 PORTA =  B000111;
 PortC =  B111000;
 delay(1000);
 PortA =  B1000000;
 delay(500);
}
```

```
exit status 1 'PortC' was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable names are difference cases and the Arduino IDE case sensitive for variable names, as are most languages and IDEs.

https://startingelectronics.org/software/arduino/learn-to-program-course/03-variables/

Rename your `PortC` variables to `PORTC` that you have declared and it should work. Alternately, switch your declaration to `PortC`, as well as changing all `PORTA`'s to `PortA`.

Using Pascal Case or CamelCase for variables and Uppercase for constants is fairly standard coding style.  Learning coding styles and techniques for maintaining code readability might help you here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style

Comment: It all makes sense now , im blind

Comment: @HamzaArshad, we all make that mistake. It's way too easy and when the compiler/IDE doesn't tell you what's wrong, it makes it so much harder to spot "simple" things like this. Arduino needs to up their IDE game and add a JIT debugger, with a whole bunch of other useful missing features. BTW, don't forget to up vote and accept this as the answer, if it really fixed your issues.

Comment: i tried upvoting but this error pops up    "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: It looks like you only have 6 reputation points, so that makes sense. You could still Accept the answer (check mark below the voting), and that might get you some points, too. I don't remember if it does or not, but it at least marks the Question as Answered.